# persist each text field in a separate row

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

i have the following code , i believe that this is not the right way to do what im trying to do..

here is what i want to accomplish

i have a page to add a new language key and the translation for that key .
the translation text-boxes are dynamic (coming from the language table) .
the name of each text field is the locale for that language (which is also stored in the language table) and i use it to get the language id (which is linked in the translation table)

### here is my database tables

### language

id (AI)     --------> languageid

locale

languageName

---

### translation

id (AI)

languageid

languagekey

translation

---

so from the language table i get the list of text boxes that should be there and loop though them

and when the user hits save i use the following way  to save what he entered

```
   if ($form->isValid()) {
      print_r($form->getData()); // debug

      foreach($form->getData() as $key => $value){ // get the submitted data
        $oTranslation = new Translations(); // creat a new entity object 
        if($key == 'languageKey'){ // if it was the language key text field
          $languageKey = $value;
          continue;
        }
        $locale = $key; // the locale to extract the language id later on
        $translation = $value;
        //----- start getting the language id
        $language = $this->getDoctrine()
                    ->getRepository('CodeizSDBTranslatorBundle:Languages');
        $query = $language->createQueryBuilder('l')
                           ->select('l.id')
                           ->where('l.locale = :locale')
                           ->setParameter('locale' , $locale)
                           ->getQuery();
        $id = $query->getResult();
        //----- end getting the language id

        $oTranslation->setLanguageId($id[0]['id']); // setting the vlaues
                     $oTranslation->setLanguageKey($languageKey);
                     $oTranslation->setTranslation($translation);
                  $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
      $em->persist($oTranslation); 
      $em->flush();// getting them into the database
      }


      return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('codeiz_sdb_translator_addlanguagekey')); // redirect to some place
  }
```

i know what i did get's the job done but  here is my question ..

is they way im saving the data to the DB correct or is there a better way ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `Translation` entity has a relation with `Locale`, you can easily create a form for `Translation` with three fields: `language_id` (entity type), `language_key` and `translation` (both text type). Your entity type should be NOT multiple. Look at [Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html). This way you can reduce controller code to just a few lines.

Also take a look at [Doctrine associations](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html). <s>I can't show you some code right now (I'm using my phone) but I'm sure you'll quickly find the way</s>.

**EDIT**: basically your form will look like:

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;

class TranslationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('language_id', 'entity', array(
                'class'    => 'AcmeHelloBundle:Language', // The entity
                'property' => 'language_name',            // The label to show
        ))
        ->add('language_key')
        ->add('translation');
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'translation';
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add the right association between `Translation` and `Language` (probably you want unidirectional many-to-one association). And, of course, validation rules (look at [Count](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Count.html)).

This assumes you are using at least Symfony 2.1.0.

Comment: hmm i didnt know that there is such a thing thanks for that it... but what about saving the values .. is there a better way rather than getting the id of the language with a query then putting it into the translation entity

Comment: again thanks a million .. im still learning symfony .. you have helped me a lot :)

Comment: @codeiz just read how entity type works, there is no need for an additional query! Just ensure that your entity is VALID, then persist. You'll get a new row in your translation table.